# Angular 6 HttpInterceptor prevent output of errors

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, catch-exception

I would like to have a HTTPInterceptor to handle all Errors. My code looks like this:

```
return next.handle(req)
  .pipe(
    catchError((response: any) => {
      if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
          console.log('error catched';

          return empty();
        }
      }

      return throwError(response);
    })
  );
```

but when running a code which produces a 401 error

```
return this.http
  .post(`${environment.baseAPIUrl}/identity/login`, { 'user': user, 'pwd': pwd})
  .pipe(
    tap(res => this.setToken(res)),
    shareReplay()
  );
```

the output is like that:

```
POST http://xyz 401 (Unauthorized)
error catched
```

so I can handle the error but I can't prevent the error output. What am I doing wrong?

best

Ingmar

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a debugger statement in and then stepping through the code to see if it's still hitting the line following line?

```
return throwError(response);
```

I agree with you, that it seems it shouldn't be bubbling up the error if it's not hitting that line.